# convert a few 2-tuples to a list of lists

Tags: ocaml

this is a question about ocaml lists and tuples. I have some 2-tuples of numbers (either integers or floats) and I want to convert it to a list of lists (with 2 elements). Assuming that I have defined a num type Int of int | Float of float, the conversion should give the following:

```
((1,1.0),(0.4,1),(0,0)) => [[Int 1;Float 1.0];[Float 0.4; Int 1];[Int 0;Int 0]]
```

or more precisely

```
 let a = (1,1.0) and b = (0.4,1) and c = (0,0) in
        myconversion (a,b,c) ;;
  => [[Int 1;Float 1.0];[Float 0.4; Int 1];[Int 0;Int 0]]
```

the point being the values a, b, c... are defined in several places in the source files (by people who use different signatures for their tuples).

The difficulty here is that I don't know the types of the elements of the 2-tuples (int or float, that varies depending on the tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who answered. I finally found a solution, using a bit of magic:

```
# type num = Int of int | Float of float;;
# let to_num x = if Obj.is_int (Obj.repr x) then
                   Int (Obj.magic (Obj.repr x) : int)
                 else
                   Float ((Obj.magic (Obj.repr x) : float));;
# let pair_to_num (a,b) = [to_num a; to_num b];;
# let myconversion (a,b,c) = [pair_to_num a; pair_to_num b; pair_to_num c];;
```

and the test:

```
# myconversion ((1,1.0),(0.4,1),(0,0));;
- : num list list = [[Int 1; Float 1.]; [Float 0.4; Int 1]; [Int 0; Int 0]]

# myconversion ((0,0),(1,1.0),(0.4,1));;
- : num list list = [[Int 0; Int 0]; [Int 1; Float 1.]; [Float 0.4; Int 1]]
```

Magic, the order does not matter and the type is recorded! I can then follow didier's idea to get rid of the pair of superfluous parentheses.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think about runtime representation: you're lucky these values aren't using  int64, or two  boxed values with the same size!

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't actual OCaml coding! :-) Using `Obj.magic` means that your code has no guaranteed meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Your input data can't be represented in OCaml as you describe it. OCaml is strongly typed. For example, your example input list is an invalid value in OCaml:

```
# [(1,1.0);(0.4,1);(0,0)];;
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

So what you describe as the essence of your problem (not knowing the types) is in fact not possible. You'll have to use some other method of representing the input. For example, you could just use floats for everything. Or you could use pairs of strings.

**Update**

The answer for the rewritten question is the same. In OCaml it's not possible *not* to know the type of something statically; i.e., at the time you're writing the program (unless it can be any type at all). It's not possible (or necessary) to query the type of something at runtime. So your question doesn't have an answer (at least as far as I can see).

For OCaml, you have to think with the type system rather than against it. After a while you start to really like it (or at least that's how it worked for me). I'd start by writing down the type you want your function `myconverstion` to have.

**Update 2**

I'll repeat my advice to treat your inputs as strings. Assuming you've parsed your input up into pairs of strings, here's some code that does what you want:

```
let myconversion coords =
    let c1 s =
        if String.contains s '.' then
           Float (float_of_string s)
        else
           Int (int_of_string s)
    in
    let cp (a, b) = [c1 a; c1 b] in
    List.map cp coords
```

Here's how it works for your input (reinterpreted as strings):

```
# myconversion [("1", "1.0"); ("0.4", "1"); ("0", "0")];;
- : fi list list = [[Int 1; Float 1.]; [Float 0.4; Int 1]; [Int 0; Int 0]]
```

**Update 3**

Here's some (crude) code that parses a file of numbers into coordinates represented as pairs of strings. It should work as long as the tuples in the input are well formed.

```
let coords fname =
    let ic = open_in fname in
    let len = in_channel_length ic in
    let buf = Buffer.create 128 in
    let () = Buffer.add_channel buf ic len in
    let () = close_in ic in
    let s = Buffer.contents buf in
    let nums = Str.(split (regexp "[^0-9.]+") s) in
    let rec mkcoords sofar = function
    | [] | [_] -> List.rev sofar
    | a :: b :: rest -> mkcoords ((a, b) :: sofar) rest
    in
    mkcoords [] nums
```

Comment: indeed there is a typo in my question, the input is `[(1,1.0),(0.4,1),(0,0)]`. So it is about converting a tuple of tuples into a list of list. I am editing my question.

Comment: Where do these numbers of unknown type come from? You can't generate things of unknown type in OCaml.

Comment: The datas are coordinate points in the plane. a has coordinate (1,1.0), b is (0.4,1) etc. I may have to handle the path a,b,c,... or the path b,c,a... There are thousands of these data points, I think the coordinates were just copy-pasted from some data file in another language that does not differentiate between int and float, hence the inconsistent typing of the tuples.

Comment: I suggest you treat them as strings. You can look at a string to see if it looks like a float or an int. Everything else will work like you want after that.

Comment: You have to work *with* the type system in OCaml. Although you can create tuples of arbitrary values in your source code, it's not going to be in a form that you can process systematically. Personally I would move the data to a separate file and parse it.

Comment: I finally found a solution recorded below. Thanks for your answer, it helped clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct problems in your setup:

1. you don't know the type of the tuples parameters
2. you want to pass them as a single n-ary tuple

For problem 2, you would have to write a function for that type specifically, whereas you could mimic a type level list type by nesting couple of tuples:

```
myconversion a,(b,c) ;;
```

The reason is that with that setup, you could write a recursive polymorphic function on the type level list:

```
val myconversion : type a b. (a,b) -> num list
```

There would still be a problem on the last element though.

So, assuming that you could pass a sequence to your conversion function, and have it process elements of that sequence one by one, you would still need to find a way of selecting the proper function of pair conversion from the tuple type: that's basically ad-hoc polymorphism, ie. you would need to be able to overload a function on its parameters' types<sup>(1)</sup>. Unfortunately, OCaml doesn't support that out of the box.

One possibility would be *perhaps* (I have no experience doing that) to implement an extension which would extract the type information of a given expression, and generate the correct code to process it in your own code.

A flexible technique consists in having that extension generate an algebraic description of the tuples types, and use that description as an equality witness in the code which will process the tuples:

```
type _ w =
    | U : (unit * unit) w
    | IF : 'a w -> ((int * float) * 'a) w
    | FI : 'a w -> ((float * int) * 'a) w
    (* other constructors if necessary *)

(* data *)
let a = 1,1.0
let b = 2.0, 2
let c = 3.0, 3
let d = 4, 4.0
let l = a,(b, (c,(d,((),()))))

(* witness *)
let w = IF (FI (FI (IF U)))
  (* the type parameter of w should be the same as l type *)

let rec conv : type a b. (a * b) w -> (a * b) -> num list = fun w (x, xs) ->
    match w with
          U -> []
        | IF w' -> let i,f = x in (Int I)::(Float f)::(conv  w' xs)
        (* etc *)
```

Here, we encode the type level `nil` list as `(unit * unit) w`.

A coalgebraic approach would require to register function overloads to the conversion function polymorphic signature within the extension, and let it pick the right one from the function overload dictionary.

---

<sub>There's a [discussion](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1655) on that topic on the LtU site.</sub>

Comment: Concerning problem 2, this is not so important because I know how many tuples I have, I have edited my question for clarity. Your answer is quite interesting nonetheless. Finally I have found a solution, recorded in the answers section. It seems that one can fake adhoc polymorphism with a bit of magic, at least for int/floats.